# Position span in top right corner in MaterializeCSS Collection

Tags: html, css, materialize

I need to position a span in a CollectionItem in top right corner or align in the middle, but is staying in bottom corner, the problem is with the first Item.

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Materialize Example</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <style media="screen">
      .wrap {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .wrap span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s3 #01579b light-blue darken-4">
          <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item" style="padding:5px;">
              Title
              <small><br />First Line</small><span class="secondary-content wrap">17</span>
          </li>
            <li class="collection-item">Texto2<span class="secondary-content">2</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s9 #00b8d4 cyan accent-4" style="color:white;">
          bbb
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use Materialize's `right` class? http://codeply.com/go/UiUFBvEIVm

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Materialize Example</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <style media="screen">
      .wrap {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .wrap span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s3 #01579b light-blue darken-4">
          <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item" style="padding:5px;">
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Title
              <small><br /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;First Line</small><span class="secondary-content wrap">17</span>
          </li>
            <li class="collection-item">Texto2<span class="secondary-content">2</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s9 #00b8d4 cyan accent-4" style="color:white;">
          bbb
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```